# Google Drive SDK for Portable Libraries

Tags: .net, google-drive-api, portable-class-library

I am in process of creating an application for Winforms. I have plans to ship this application for Windows Phone later. So I decided to use Portable libraries. I have following Target frameworks for my portable libraries:

```
.NET Framework 4 and higher
Silverlight 4 and higher
Windows Phone 7 and higher
.NET for Windows Store apps
```

In my portable libraries, I have referenced following libraries from Google drive SDK:

```
DotNetOpenAuth.dll
Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2.dll
Google.Apis.dll
Google.Apis.Drive.V2.dll
Google.Apis.OAuth2.V2.dll
log4net.dll
Newtonsoft.Json.Net35.dll
```

Till now when I build my solution, it works fine as I have these references anywhere. But when I use these references in my code like:

```
using Google.Apis.Authentication;
using File = Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File;
public interface IUtilities
{
    void SampleMethod(IAuthenticator authenticator, File file);
}
```

Now, I get NO compilation error. However when I try building the solution I get following

```
Error   1   The type or namespace name 'IAuthenticator' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Error   3   The type or namespace name 'Google' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

If I write more code using these libraries, I get error for all those objects in similar way. Can anyone help me to understand this? Let me know if you need any more info. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Any libraries you reference from a Portable Class Library must also be portable (and support compatible platforms).  Json.NET has a portable version, but the other libraries you are using probably don't.  You could get the source code to those libraries and port them to PCLs, or you can create portable abstractions for the functionality they provide and use those abstractions to allow you to call into platform-specific code.

Here are some sources of more information about using Portable Class Libraries:

- Blog Post: [How to Make Portable Class Libraries Work for You](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsplaisted/archive/2012/08/27/how-to-make-portable-class-libraries-work-for-you.aspx)
- BUILD presentation: [Create Cross-platform Apps using Portable Class Libraries](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2012/3-004)
- Community samples and links to more information: [pcl.codeplex.com](http://pcl.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Daniel: But I believe if non PCLs are referenced in PCL, we should get compilation error. Or it should not allow us to reference them. I have tried this. But I am not sure, why I am getting runtime error. However I will have a look at the given references although I have visited few of them and many more before. But this time, will look at them more seriously. Thanks

Comment: @rapsalands Yes, it would be reasonable to have an error when you try to reference an invalid DLL.  You will get an error if you try to add a project-to-project reference that is not supported, or if you try to add a reference to a NuGet package that doesn't support your target platform.  File references to DLLs are the only situation where you won't get an error.  Over time I think more libraries will migrate to NuGet so it will be less of an issue.

Comment: I got your point. But how would I be able to know that which feature is causing the build fail. I mean, if I am getting compilation error then I can migrate those parts in interface. But if there is no error then it will be very difficult to pick the features which are making my solution to fail.